# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of '' with no type

Tags: c++, struct

I got `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'InvalidSig' with no type` of the below header file, how to solve it?

```
struct args{
    InvalidSig* context; //error
    string mname;
};

class InvalidSig{
    .......
}
```

Comment: Use a *forward declaration*: Add `class InvalidSig;` before defining `struct args`.

Comment: @Cameron why should I do this?

Comment: @user4016367 Because that is the way to fix the error in your code. You can't refer to a type before it has been declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward declare `class InvalidSig` above:

```
class InvalidSig;

struct args {
    InvalidSig* context;
    // ...
};
```

You can also do this, if you only want to use the name once before its definition:

```
struct args {
    class InvalidSig* context;
    // ...
};
```

I recommend avoiding the latter though, as the former is more common and will be less confusing to anyone reading your code.